# c combining numbers from each line in a text file

Tags: c, text-files, scanf

I have a text file with lots of lines, ill copy paste some of them in here to show you what im working with.

1        16.07.2011 kl. 17.00    OB - FCN      2 - 0      6.965
1        17.07.2011 kl. 14.00    FCM - SIF     1 - 2      5.370

2        23.07.2011 kl. 17.00    SIF - BIF     0 - 1      4.173
2        23.07.2011 kl. 19.00    FCK - OB      2 - 2     14.774
3        30.07.2011 kl. 17.00    AGF - OB      2 - 2     11.312
3        30.07.2011 kl. 19.00    FCK - FCN     2 - 0     11.076

```
while (fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %lf\n", &runde, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10)
    int prev_goal = goal1 + goal2;
    int current;
    if(prev_goal > current) {
    printf("Runde %d var den mest målrige med %d mål\n", runde, prev_goal);
   }
```

I get the values into different variables, but how can i add the results from each round and see which one has the most goals in it? Any advice would be appriciated!
Thank you :)

Comment: Tried adding goal1 goal2 into a new variable, but cant really seem to get it to work

Comment: Can you show that non-working code?

Comment: Danmark, ikke sant?

See @nonsensical's answer below.

Comment: Jo, ja men den virker sku ikke helt :(

Answer (score 1):

I will make the assumption that you only care about which round had the most goals in it and that you don't need to store your text file in memory like @Ben suggested.

If that's the case the you can do something like this:

```
int i, maxGoals = 0, roundWithMostGoals = 0;

for (i = 0; fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %lf\n", &runde, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10; ++i)
{
    if (maxGoals < goal1 + goal2)
    {
        roundWithMostGoals = runde;
        maxGoals = goal1 + goal2;
    }
}

// Edit:
printf("The largest number of goals was %d, scored in round %d", maxGoals, roundWithMostGoals);
```

**This code does have a problem**. If there are two rounds with the largest number of goals only the first one will be printed.

To avoid this we would need to loop through twice which is not ideal and I would recommend going with one of the other proposed approaches that loads all of this data into memory.

However, here is a modified solution like the one above even though I don't think it is optimal:

```
int i, maxGoals = 0, roundWithMostGoals = 0;

// Find the maximum number of goals that was scored in any one round.
for (i = 0; fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %lf\n", &runde, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10; ++i)
{
    if (maxGoals < goal1 + goal2)
    {
        maxGoals = goal1 + goal2;
    }
}

printf("The largest number of goals scored was %d.\n", maxGoals);
printf("The largest number of goals was scored in\n");

// TODO: Reposition the file stream back to the beginning or close it and then reopen it again.
// XXX Code Here XXX

// Loop through again getting all the rounds with the maximum number of goals.

for (i = 0; fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %lf\n", &runde, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10; ++i)
{
    if (maxGoals == goal1 + goal2)
    {
        printf("\tRound %d\n", runde);
    }
}
```

But this now loops through twice and is definitely not the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but when i print it out i get several rounds and not the exact amount of goals.

Comment: Where do you print from? I've edited my post to print the largest number of goals scored and what round it occurred in.

Comment: Somehow i only get the goals from the first match in the round that has the most goals.. hmm

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are iterating over rounds. Could you please explain, in a little more detail, what your data actually represents? It would be the same construct but iterating over a different part for matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some arrays:

```
int goal1Array[]
int goal2Array[]
int listLength = 0;
```

Then as you read in the goals you can add them to the arrays (make sure you record how many you are adding):

```
goal1Array[9] = goal1;
listLength++;
```

NOTE: You will need to do some dynamic memory management. Look up c arrays etc.

At the end you can loop through this list to compare them:

```
for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    /*compare stuff*/
}
```

This is just some general advice you will need to put some effort into getting this to compile without memory errors.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out tomorrow! :)

Comment: @Winkz What do you need help with. I suspect this is a homework assignment so im not going to give you the answer. Its a pretty simple concept, keep going through the file and store the answers in arrays. Here is a tutorial on dynamic arrays http://fydo.net/gamedev/dynamic-arrays ask a specific help question and i will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of ints with an int for each team. They will be your sums for each team.

Then, [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) the names of team1 and team2 with the names of your teams. Then, add the goals to their associated goalSum.

```
int goalSum[3];
goalSum[0] = 0;goalSum[1] = 0;goalSum[2] = 0


while (fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %lf\n", &runde, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10)
{

    //comparisions for the first team
    if(strcmp(team1,"nameofteam0")==0)
    {
            ++goalSum[0];
    }
    if(strcmp(team1,"nameofteam1")==0)
    {
            ++goalSum[1];
    }
    if(strcmp(team1,"nameofteam2")==0)
    {
            ++goalSum[2];
    }
    //comparisions for the second team
    if(strcmp(team2,"nameofteam0")==0)
    {
            ++goalSum[0];
    }
    if(strcmp(team2,"nameofteam1")==0)
    {
            ++goalSum[1];
    }
    if(strcmp(team2,"nameofteam2")==0)
    {
            ++goalSum[2];
    }
}
```

Then, compare the goals of each team.

```
    const int numberOfTeams = 3;
    int winningTeam=0;

//You'll have to do the support for draws yourself.
    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfTeams; ++i)
    {
        if(sumOfGoal[i]>sumOfGoal[i+1])
        {
                winningTeam = i+1;
        }
        else
        {
                winningTeam = i+2;
        }
    }
    printf("Team%i wins!\n", winningTeam);
```